# Copying a row and pasting it at the bottom of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy row 2 from a sheet and paste it to the last empty row in another sheet (Sheet2). So far, this is what I came up with:

```
Sub testj()

Rows(2).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert

End Sub
```

This gives the error: subscript out of range. I can't seem to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Which line of code produces the error? Since the problem is specific to the file the code is being run on we can't guess which line is causing the error - it could be either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Renamed Worksheet?!

When you run your code and there is no worksheet with the name "Sheet2" (in the **Tab**):

**Run-time error: '9' Subscript out of range**

When you have no data from A2 to the bottom in worksheet with the name "Sheet2":

**Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error**

To conclude: You might have accidentally renamed "Sheet2". To avoid this you can use the **code name** of the sheet like this:

```
Rows(2).Copy
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

Now you can rename the sheet in the **Tab** as you wish.

### The Last Used Cell in a Column

If you are 100% sure that there is data in at least the first two rows and your data is contiguous (no empty cells), your code works fine. If the data in the column is not contiguous, the first empty cell at which it stops won't be the last. So you will overwrite existing data.

Therefore the last cell in a column is mostly calculated from the bottom like this:

```
Rows(2).Copy
Sheet2.cells(Rows.count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

This has the limitation that it will never copy into Row 1, but since you usually have headers there it is fine.

A way without limitation is using the [Find Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727142/how-to-find-the-first-and-last-populated-cell-in-a-range-with-whitespace/53733361#53733361).

Comment: I was about to post about the worksheet name and this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802080/subscript-out-of-range-error-vba-error  but I think I wouldn't have as detailed an answer as yours so if it's OK, I'll just attach that there incase it comes in useful for anyone wondering about the `ActiveWorksheet` and more answers on `subscript out of range `